# How can I make a program start up automatically in OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, launchd

I have a little program that I want to make open automatically when my mac is started up.

Because this program accepts command line arguments, its not as simple as just going to System Prefs/Accounts/Login items and adding it there...

From google, I read that I can create a .profile file in my user's home folder, and that will execute whatever I put in it... So I have a .profile page in ~ like this:

-rw-r--r--@  1 matt  staff     27 27 Sep 13:36 .profile

That contains this...

/Applications/mousefix 3.5

But it doesn't execute on startup! If I enter "/Applications/mousefix 3.5" manually into the terminal, it does work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your .profile is supposed to run when you open a terminal, not on startup and not when you log in to the GUI. Is that working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From here and into the future, look into [`launchd`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmacosx%2Flaunchd.html&ei=JKHjSLHbH5GMpwT2_tH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNH84xt1QnHIRkhYtYJtGScdITegxQ&sig2=xYVn27D-CXFP8IbLig9-qg) for what you want to do. All other methods have been deprecated or are now unsupported. This is probably a bit more heavy-weight than what you want, though.

It could also be a problem with your version of the bash shell not correctly executing your `.profile`. Try putting the command into `.bashrc` in your home directory, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Lingon](http://tuppis.com/lingon/) to help construct a plist file for launchd.

Answer (score 3):

The most general way of launching things on startup on MacOS is using [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html). You can create a plist file to tell it to launch your program on startup, which can include arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Applescript which can run terminal commands, then have that applescript launched at startup.

Answer (score 1):

The `.profile` and `.bash_profile` only come into play when you open a new shell (ie. opening Terminal or entering through SSH). Also, I believe if bash detects `.bash_profile` it won't look for `.profile`
If you want it start upon login, I would look at the other suggestions about launchd

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a wrapper script that runs it with the arguments you want

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. The launchd solution is pretty cool, yes its heavyweight for such a simple thing, but its good to know, and as a developer I'm happy to tinker about :)

Comment: launchd isn't really all that heavyweight - it goes to some lengths to be as efficient as possible for what it does. It's Open Source so you can check it out yourself if you like:  http://launchd.macosforge.org/