# Detect/wait user login on Linux/Mac with c++?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, authentication

I'm writing a C/C++ program that I'd like to have run when a user logs on to their Mac or Linux machine.

I'm thinking of starting my app when kernel finishes loading. This app will be listen user login signal. When it receives the signal, it will then run my other app.

Is this a good strategy? Is there a better way to have my app automatically run when a user logs on to their machine?

Comment: Why not just add app X to the users' startup scripts (or the Mac equivalent)? Then you wouldn't have to wait or watch for anything. The OS will start it for you. See [How can I make a program start up automatically in OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158388)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are better ways:

- For Mac OS X you want to use `launchd(8)`. (See [Apple's Daemons and Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) and the [man page for `launchd(8)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html).)
- For KDE there is [Autostart](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html).
- For Gnome you can use the [Default Session](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/sessions-3.html.en) or the system wide [Configuration of the GNOME Display Manager](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en).
- In the old days of X11 there used to be a file called `.xinitrc` (see the [man page for `xinit(1)`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xinit.1.html)) or `.xsession` (see the [man page for `xdm(1)`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xdm.1.html)).

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a cron job to observe the logged in users, and when the list changes, act accordingly.

Comment: No way! This is busy waiting. You should use [lauchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)!

Comment: Concur -- went for ultra simple.